# The variety induced by an extension of a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, covering-spaces, ramification, field-extensions

If $K$ is a finitely generated field extension of $k$, then there exists an irreducible affine $k$-variety with function field $K$. The idea is that if $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are generators of $K$ under $k$, i.e each elements of $K$ is a rational function in $x_1, \dots , x_n$, then the kernel of the map $k[t_1,\dots, t_n]\to K$ is a prime ideal and the induced map between their field fractions is an isomorphism:

$(k[t_1,\dots, t_n]/I)_0\cong K$

This means $Z(I)\subseteq k^n$ is the affine irreducible variety which field fraction corresponds to $K$.

Now I have the following problem:

[image]

In this case I have $k$ equal to the function field of $\mathbb{P}^2$, and $K$ equal to the finite extension $k((\frac{l_2}{l_1})^{\frac{1}{n}},\dots, , (\frac{l_k}{l_1})^{\frac{1}{n}})$. In the paper the author tells us $K$ determine an algebraic (affine?) surface $X$ with normal singularities and a natural map $\pi: X\to \mathbb{P}^2$.

I don't understand how to define this natural map $\pi$ and what is exactly this surface $X$. I think that $K$ determine an affine variety up to birational morphisms and so I don't understand how to define exactly $X$.

Can you give me an example for $n=2$ and $k=3$, please?

Comment: You can take the normalisation of $\mathbf P^2$ in the larger field.

Comment: Can you explain me please?

Comment: One place you can read about relative normalisation is Tag [035H](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035H). I don't know what your background is, so it's hard to say more.

Comment: I know the concept of normalization but I don't understand the phrase 'in the larger field'

Comment: I believe the author of the paper refers to a special realization of one element of the birational class as you pointed out. That one should be hinted by the generators of the field extension presented. For instance in the case you asked for in the end of your post one equation should be $z_1/z_0\sqrt{\ell_2/\ell_1}-z_2/z_0\sqrt{\ell_3/\ell_1}=0$. Notice that this is "above" $z_1/z_0*(\ell_2/\ell_1)-z_2/z_0*(\ell_3/\ell_1)=0$.

Comment: You have a finite field extension $K \to L$ and a normal (even smooth) variety $X$ with fraction field $K$. Then you can take the normalisation of $X$ in $L$, meaning on each affine open $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ (so $\operatorname{Frac} A = K$) you take the integral closure of $A$ in $L$, and glue these together for the various $U \subseteq X$. (The cited tag is merely a coordinate-free way to phrase this: the pushforward of $\mathcal O_L$ is a quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-module, and you take the relative Spec of the integral closure of $\mathcal O_X$ in $\mathcal O_L$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to turn my comment into an answer not because it is complete but because I think it can be of use.

Let $z=(z_0:z_1:z_2)$ and $u=(u_1:\ldots:u_k)$ be homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$. First notice that the surface $X_1\subset \mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^{k-1}$ defined by the vanishing of the $2\times 2$-minors of the matrix \begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1} & u_{2} & \cdots & u_{k} \\
\ell_{1} & \ell_{2} & \cdots & \ell_{k} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} is the closure of the graph of the rational map $z\mapsto (\ell_1:\ldots:\ell_k)$. Restricting the projection you get a well defined map $X_1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$.

On the other hand you also have a $n$-to-$1$ map $\mathbb{P}^{k-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{k-1}$ given by $\phi_n:(t_1:\ldots:t_k)\mapsto (t^n_1:\ldots:t^n_k)$. This induces $id\times\phi_n:\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^{k-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$. Now you can take $X$ to be the preimage of $X_1$ by $id\times\phi_n$.

In this way you can "see" $X\subset \mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^{k-1}$ with coordinates $(z,t)$ as the vanishing set of minors of the matrix

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
t^n_{1} & t^n_{2} & \cdots & t^n_{k} \\
\ell_{1} & \ell_{2} & \cdots & \ell_{k} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Also the map $\pi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ is clear. The ramification locus is induced by the ramification locus of $\phi_n$.

I'm not sure about the singularities of $X$ but I think they will depend on the relative position of lines $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k$.

Comment: The problem is that the group $(Z/nZ)^k$ acts on $X$  and not $(Z/nZ)^{k-1}$. What is the mistake?

Comment: The group acting effectively is $(Z/nZ)^{k-1}$, because the element $(-1,\ldots,-1) \in (Z/nZ)^k$ acts trivially on the homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: Yes, ok, but this would mean simply that the elements of the type $(a,...,a)$ belongs to the stabilizer of each point, right? We are interested only of that actions that are faithful,  so this mean we must consider the new faithful action $((Z/nZ)^k)/(\cap_x G_x)$, that is isomorphic exactly to (Z/nZ)^{k-1} via the isomorphism $(a_1,..,a_k)\to (a_2-a_1, \cdots , a_k-a_1)$ ?

Comment: Can you help me also for this question, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3815141

Answer (score 1):

Let  $n=2$ and $k=3$, and suppose by the sake of simplicity that the three lines are in general position. Then, up to projective transformations, we can assume that they are the three coordinate lines $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, $\ell_3$ given by $z_0=0$, $z_1=0$, $z_2=0$, respectively.

Then your function field is simply $\mathbb{C}(x, \, y)(\sqrt{x}, \, \sqrt{y})$, where $x=z_1/z_0$, $y=z_2/z_0$, and the affine equation of your $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$-cover $X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ on the chart $z_0 \neq 0$ is $$(x, \, y) \mapsto (x^2, \, y^2).$$

Note that $X$ is projective, since it is a finite covering of a projective variety; in fact, $X$ is the union of three of these affine charts, corresponding to the three standard charts for $\mathbb{P}^2$.

A moment of thought shows that $X = \mathbb{P}^2$, and that the *global* equation of your bi-double cover is $$\pi \colon \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2, \quad [z_0: \, z_1: \, z_2] \mapsto [z_0^2: \, z_1^2: \, z_2^2].$$

It is an instructive exercise to factor $\pi$ through the three *singular* double covers $$X_i \to \mathbb{P}^2, \quad i=1,\, 2, \, 3$$ corresponding to the three non-trivial involutions in the Klein group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.

Comment: But in this case $\pi$ would be a $(Z/2Z)^3$ covering and not a $(Z/2Z)^2$-covering, right?

Comment: If $k=3$ then $k-1=2$. The covering in the affine chart is clearly a bi-double cover, non tri-double. So the extension to the projective plane must be bi-double, too. Recall that $z_0$, $z_1$, $z_2$ are homogeneous coordinates. Think of the double cover given in affine coordinates by $x \mapsto x^2$: in homogeneous coordinates it becomes $[z_0 \, : \,z_1] \mapsto[z_0^2 \, : \,z_1^2]$.

Comment: This is double and *not* bi-double, for instance because $[z_0:z_1]=[-z_0: -z_1]$ and $[-z_0:z_1]=[z_0:-z_1]$.